# JSF: how can i save stream as file outside of webapp and how to access it when deployed as war

Tags: java, jsf, deployment, glassfish, primefaces

I have couple of questions here.

1. I am using the following to write a stream to a file. I want to write to outside the webapp container, as on a redeploy all the files will be deleted.

   ```
               InputStream in = event.getFile().getInputstream();    
               OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + fName);


               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               int len;
               while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                   out.write(buf, 0, len);
               }
   ```
2. I do not know if we can achieve this by externalContext of facesContext. If so, please give me an example of how to do it.
3. How can I access this ? example, if i have to use it as follows, what path do i have to use?

   `EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
   attachment.setPath("mypictures/john.jpg");`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How would you determine the actual physical location on disk of "mypictures/john.jpg"?

Comment: This is my question also ? but in the example, I think it refers to the relative path of the servlet. not sure. this is just an example, i have taken from http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html

Comment: If you want to get "outside" of the servlet environment you need to know the surrounding operating system to know where you can put things.  Considered using a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything right. Use (for example) user tmp  directory to write this file (`System.getProperty("user.tmp.dir")`). To access this file use `FileInputStream` in exactly the same manner as you are using `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: thanks. it's not very clear to me. what is "user.tmp.dir" and where will the file be saved ? what would be the path as in attachment.setPath("mypictures/john.jpg") ?

Comment: Also, in jsf <h:graphicImage> always takes the path as relative path from webcontent. if it is an external file, how to specify it ?

Comment: I tried to explain the portable way to get some writable directory. Some of them are stored in System properties. To get system properties you have to call System.getProperty(propertyName). There are 2 relevant system properties: java.io.tmpdir and user.home. I think that the names are self-explainable. I did mistake in property name when I wrote the answer. The 2 names I wrote here are proved.

Comment: OK. I see. so if i use "user.home", in windows it will give me some directory and in linux some other. So, let's say in linux, System.getProperty(user.home) returns, /home/xyz and if i create a directory under this called abc and if i store a file aFile.pdf, will i be able to access it as attachment.setPath("/home/xyz/abc/aFile.pdf") ?

Comment: Exactly. You will be able to read an write to this folder. And if you are on windows prior to Win7 the directory is something like c:\Documents and Settings\Local Settings\xyz. On windows 7 it is c:\Users\xyz